# "list index out of range" while iterating strings

Tags: python, list, for-loop, oop, nltk

I'm getting an error "List out of range. Though I found the other way round for this error, but can I know how can I solve this error.
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with your `for loop` as everyone suggested. Problem is with `synset` for the word **'the'** as synset entry for **'the'** does not exist. You can replace your code with the below code:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    synset = wordnet.synsets(words[i])
    if synset:
        print ("Synonym of the word "+words[i]+" in the list is: "+synset[0].lemmas()[0].name())
    else:
        print ("Synonym of the word "+words[i]+" not found in the list")
```

Output:

```
Synonym of the word After in the list is: after
Synonym of the word getting in the list is: acquiring
Synonym of the word the not found in the list
Synonym of the word proper in the list is: proper
Synonym of the word co-ordinates in the list is: coordinate
```

Hope the above code helps you out!

Answer (score 2):

`len` in this case is 5, so range is creating a range that goes from 0 up to 5, whereas your list indexes go from 0 to 4.

You could rewrite that line as:

```
for i in range(len(words)-1):
```

Otherwise, if you only need the word and not an index you could just write

```
for word in words:
```

Finally, if you need both the word and an index you could use `enumerate()`

```
for i, word in enumerate(words, start=0):
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the len() function or the range() function. You can just use:

```
for i in words:
  synset = wordnet.synsets(i)
  print(i + synset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the range to be:

```
len(words) - 1
```

So the `for` loop will be:

```
for i in range(len(words)-1):
```

`len(words)` will return the literal number count of the length, but when iterating over the range, the range begins at 0, so you want your range to be len(words) - 1

Answer (score 0):

```
len()
```

The function gives the output as 5 in this case, because the counter starts from 1 instead of 0.
So if you want to loop through the list, use:

```
for i in range(len(words) - 1):
```

This will count up to the last element instead of going over and giving an error.